# Email says it is from nobody

Tags: php

I have recently tried to use the php mail function to send out confirmation emails and I have been successful in doing so. However, when I added a few things to my script, something doesn't seem to work.

The code below is the code that I got to work. Everything that I need for the email to contain appears.

```
$to        = 'Myemail';
$subject = 'Confirmation';
$message = 'This is a test';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit' . "\r\n\r\n" .
    'From: fromemail'."\r\n" .  
    'Reply-To: replyemail' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

However, when I transfer the same headers to another script (Below), the mail delivers but there are a few issues.

1) My mail says that the mail is from nobody.
2) Instead of the headers appearing in the info area, it appears as text in the mail
From: from email
Reply-To: reply email 
X-Mailer: PHP/5.2.9

The script below is being included in another program i wrote, so i am wondering if that is the problem. I don't think its syntax because its the same headers I used above.  I have attached a picture of the mail I get. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSDyo.jpg

Your help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <?php
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        if ($message != null) {
            include("connect.php");
            $extract = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contact` ORDER BY `id`") or die("Error");
            $counter = 0;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($extract)) {
                $email[$counter] = $row['email'];
                $counter++;
            }
            for ($x = 0; $x < $counter; $x++) {
                $to = $email[$x];
                $subject = $subject;
                $message = $message;
                $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
                        'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
                        'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit' . "\r\n\r\n" .
                        'From: fromemail' . "\r\n" .
                        'Reply-To: replyemail' . "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                echo "EMAIL WAS SENT TO: ";
                echo $email[$x];
                echo "<BR>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Random note - I believe the `From:` thing is normally structured as: `From: First Last <email@address.com>`

Comment: just my preference but I would modify $headers to use only double quotes so you can avoid that screwy looking jive you got there. Also, you're setting a real email and not fromemail, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit' . "\r\n\r\n" .
//---------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
// Two line breaks ends the header block
// These remaining headers are seen as part of the message body
'From: fromemail'."\r\n" .  
'Reply-To: replyemail' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

You have an extra line break here, which completes the headers portion of the message before the `From` and subsequent headers.  Remove the extra `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you may need to set the `-f` switch to set the envelope from address in order to resolve the From nobody error for some email clients, like so:

```
$from = 'email@example.com';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f' . $from);
```

This is of course in addition to the header error that Michael has corrected.

Comment: Ah i see, out of curiosity, why does it work in the first code?

Comment: Setting the -f helps some mail clients (Outlook, notably) to match the From header with a Sender. Not setting the -f may result in Outlook reporting things like "From Apache@localhost on behalf of fromemail@example.com"