# Javascript/ PHP events update sign up button

Tags: php, javascript, email

I'm trying to design a basic Javascript email sign up to events update, just like you see on under construction and coming soon pages. A visitor will add their email and click submit to add themselves to the email list, with a basic Ajax or jQuery "thank you for signing up" message. Also I would need to use a PHO email validator.

HTML

```
<form action="scripts/mail.php" method="POST">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email here....." tabindex="1">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Signup" class="submit-btn" tabindex="2">
</form>
```

With the PHP file below:

```
<?php
  $from = "events@spectator.co.uk";
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $to = "datunrase@pressholdings.com";
  $subject = "Please add me to the events mailing list";
  $mailheader = "Email: $email \r\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
    "alert('Thanks! We will keep you updated');".
    "</script>";
?>
```

Then I used this Javascript SignUp.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mousedownHappened = false;
  $("#submitbtn").mousedown(function() {
    mousedownHappened = true;
  });
  $("#email").focus(function(){
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 1.0,
      width: '250px'
    }, 300, function(){
      // callback method empty
    });
    // display submit button
    $("#submitbtn").fadeIn(300);
  });
  $("#submitbtn").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $("#signup").fadeOut(230, function(){
      // callback method to display new text
      // setup other codes here to store the e-mail address
      $(this).after('<p id="success">Thanks! We will keep you updated.</p>');
    });
  });
  $("#email").blur(function(){
    if(mousedownHappened) {
      // reset mousedown and cancel fading effect
      mousedownHappened = false;
    } else {
      $("#email").animate({
        opacity: 0.75,
        width: '250px'
      }, 500, function(){
        // callback method empty
      });
      // hide submit button
      $("#submitbtn").fadeOut(400);
    }
  });
});
```

But I need help to make it function properly. First I want the email to say who it's from, but currently it says nobody.

Also I know the JS and PHP seems to override each other when it comes to the email confirmation text. So can you tell me what's best to use? And after they sign up I want the visitor to stay on the same page. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is quite ambiguous. Where exactly is your php code,and Js code, I mean which files

Comment: Sorry will send you the site i got it from http://designwoop.com/2013/01/dynamic-newsletter-signup-form-with-jquery-animations/

Comment: If you can view the code used and help me to edit it properly for me and help me understand what i need to add to fix the code and make it send an email to a particular address with the visitors email address

Comment: About the 'nobody' issue, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8319816/837154

Comment: On click of the button fire an ajax request that will call the php file, andon success of that ajax execute further

Comment: Could you show me an example please

Comment: The code in the php and what should i do to edit the js then?

Comment: Any luck helping me out showing me the code example?

Answer (score 1):

In order to correctly display the "FROM" you should set it in your $mailheader variable. Change it like this:

```
$mailheader = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '. $email . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Still need help on how to On click of the button fire an ajax request that will call the php file, andon success of that ajax execute further